# get file path of sharedpreferences file

Tags: android

I am creating a sharedpreferences file in my android code. I then want to email that file in my code. For that I need to access the path of the sharedpreferences file. The code I am using is below. But it does not seem to work. I am able to open the email but there is no attachment there since I guess it could not get the file. Can someone suggest me any solution here.

```
File f = getDatabasePath("userPrefsFile.xml");
String filelocation=f.getAbsolutePath();
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.setType("application/xml");
String[] to = {"test@test.com"};
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,filelocation);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"test file send");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send email"));
```

Answer (score 2):

So <kbd>SharedPreferences</kbd> files are located at directory

```
/data/data/your.package/shared_prefs
```

So you need to use path above.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
File root = new File("/data/data/your.package/shared_prefs");
if (root.isDirectory()) {
   for (File child: root.listFiles()) {
      Toast.makeText(this, child.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Reason why you cannot use `getDatabasePath()` is that returns databases folder <sup>1</sup>

```
/data/data/your.package/databases/
```

<sup>1</sup> Same issue is also related to `getFileStreamPath()` method that returns

```
/data/data/your.package/files
```